# How to autoupdate information from jetpack compose to monog database using textfields/dropdownmenus?

Tags: jquery, mongodb, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to figure out how I can make information within a textfield or dropdownmenu autoupdate. For example, if I choose a age of 20 in the dropdownmenu but later changes this to 25. How can I make it so this is autoupdated in mongo database and not having to select a button to save this information? Appreciate any feedback!

Main function within a repository:

```
override suspend fun updatePerson(person: Person) {
    realm.write {
        val queriedPerson =
            query<Person>(query = "_id == $0", person._id)
                .first()
                .find()
        if (queriedPerson != null) {
            queriedPerson.name = person.name
            queriedPerson.age = person.age
           

        } else {
            Log.d("MongoRepository", "Queried Person does not exist.")
        }
    }
}
```

Function to update person in a viewmodel:

```
fun updatePerson() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        if (objectId.value.isNotEmpty()) {
            MongoDB.updatePerson(person = Person().apply {
                _id = ObjectId(hexString = this@HomeViewModel.objectId.value)
                name = this@HomeViewModel.name.value
                age = this@HomeViewModel.humaneAge.value

            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can use ```debounce``` for that. It will wait for given time after your complete typing or select value from the dropdown. and once the it completes send you update to Database

Comment: hmm interesting, and how would that generally look like in code?@ChiragThummar